# "Zephyr with JIRA" integration with Selenium

Tags: selenium, jira-zephyr

We are using Zephyr with JIRA for test case management. And uploaded test cases into them. There are more than 1000 test cases. My Objective here is to use Selenium(Java) and Automate these test cases in such a way that:

1. The corresponding test case execution in Selenium needs to be triggered from JIRA
2. The corresponding result (Pass / fail) needs to be returned and updated in Zephyr
3. In case of defects, the defects needs to be created automatically

Pls let me know, anyone have implemented or tried this approach…

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully these will answer your questions:

1) Currently, Zephyr for JIRA does not come built-in with the ability to execute automation from inside the plugin. Any automation done will need to be started outside Zephyr for JIRA.

2) Using the ZAPI plugin with Zephyr for JIRA will let you automatically enter execution information into Zephyr for JIRA. Technical documentation on what methods ZAPI can do can be found at the link:
http://docs.getzephyr.apiary.io/

3) Defect creation can be done using JIRA's API. Once the defect is created, you can use ZAPI API to link the newly created defect to an execution. See the link above for information on how to do this.

Comment: Sample code to get started with Selenium and Zapi https://support.getzephyr.com/hc/en-us/articles/204713195-Integrate-Selenium-JUnit-and-ANT-with-Zephyr-for-JIRA-and-ZAPI

Answer (score 0):

There is an official documentation about Zephyr integration with selenium. You can take a look at it:

[Zephyr’s Integration with Selenium](http://www.getzephyr.com/insights/zephyr%E2%80%99s-integration-selenium)